# Override node.tpl.php for the Front Page

Tags: nodes

I am trying to override the front page node, however after following the guide from the official site, it's not working.

Guide: https://www.drupal.org/node/1585528

I have taken `node.tpl.php` and renamed it to `node--front.tpl.php` and made changes to the layout, saved and cleared cache. The changes are not being displayed.

Now if I edit node.tpl.php directly it shows the changes, anyone know what I am doing wrong to override specific node templates?

**EDIT:**
I want to move the title below the image being displayed in the front page.

See below: Moving the title block under the content block, moves the title down as I want it to do, however how do I specify this for just the front page and not all nodes? (renaming `node.tpl.php` to `node--front.tpl.php` does not work as mentioned above)

In node.tpl.php: (title block)

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

(content block)

```
<div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php
  // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
  hide($content['comments']);
  hide($content['links']);
  print render($content);
?>
```

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, renaming it from `node.tpl.php` to `node--front.tpl.php` doesn't do anything. The changes are not being displayed after renaming this. I've changed `node--front.tpl.php` back to it's original name, copied it as `homepage.tpl.php` and nothing, the changes are not being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create **page--front.tpl.php** from **page.tpl.php**. You are changing  your front page, not the node.

Comment: Please see the edit section in my question.  I am changing the content being displayed in the front page. In `page.tpl.php` this does not have a title block.

Comment: Pls refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268607/how-to-override-front-page-node-tpl-drupal

Comment: If the front page is node, the OP request makes sense. In this case, they surely don't want to change the page template.